# Does sati pratha still exist in the modern society?

Tags: india

[Sati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sati_(practice)) has been legally abolished, but can still be heard of as being practiced in some parts of India. Is there any evidence of it being illegally practiced?

Comment: This is a little like the famous legal question, "When did you stop beating your wife?" It is very difficult to prove a negative.  "still can be heard being practiced..."  If you have evidence, please include your research. Please source all non-trivial assertions.

Comment: I do not have a written evidence, but recently I have been to my village. there is a festival of praying lord shiva where few saints fast for 4 days They are only supposed to drink water. This festival comes after 12 years. This festival is celebrated in the one of the villages in bankura. One of the saints died because of fasting for 3 days and heat( saints are supposed to sleep in tents not in their homes). It seems her wife and daughter was also immolated in the fire.

Comment: So you have anecdotal evidence and you're asking how common the practice is in the modern day? Might not be appropriate for H:SE.

Comment: There are many things that go unregistered and ignored and its common in india, in but some of them have evidence, and so i wanted to know of them.

Comment: Cleaned up a bit. Note that History is by definition stuff that happened in the *past*, so questions posed in the *present tense* are likely off-topic. (Personally, I'd cut "is this historic practice still in use" questions slack, but I see 2 voters already who felt otherwise). A lot of such questions would instead be on-topic on the Politics site. Not sure about this one though.

Comment: @T.E.D. Wouldn't this be on topic on Hinduism.SE?

Comment: @called2voyage - Don't know that stack at all, so I can't say. I'd think such a stack would concentrate only on doctrinal matters rather than social, but I don't know their scope.

Comment: @T.E.D. Their [topic guidelines](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) mention questions about Hindu practices and historical questions about Hinduism.

Comment: I agree that this question might be a better fit for the Hinduism site.